# Отправить запрос с Windows на Linux, используя библиотеки Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, кодировка, sphinxsearch

Реализую приложение под Windows с использованием библиотек Qt для работы с базой данных. БД работает под СУБД Firebird, расположена на сервере с ОС GNU/Linux и имеет кодировку UNICODE_FSS. В приложении необходимо реализовать поиск записей, используя демон Sphinx.

Основная проблема с кодировкой. При отправке запроса, содержащего русские буквы, в логах запросов Sphinx-а стоят знаки вопроса.

Подключение к демону Sphinx:

```
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "Sphinx");
    db.setHostName("192.168.0.14");
    db.setPort(9306);
    db.open();
```

Отправка запроса:

```
    QByteArray ba("select id from lettersIndex where match('коллеги')");
    // Пробовал и без кодека, а так же со всевозможными кодировками
    QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
    QString query = codec->toUnicode(ba);
    q.exec(query);
```

sphinx.conf

```
source lettersSource
{
                type = firebird
                sql_host = 192.168.0.14
                sql_port = 3050
                sql_user = user
                sql_pass = password
                sql_db = 192.168.0.14/3050:rc
                sql_query = SELECT l.ID, l.USERNAME, l.CAPTION, l.BODY,\
                    DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1/1/1970 00:00:00', l.logdate) as posttime\
                    from LETTERS l
                sql_attr_timestamp = posttime
}
index lettersIndex
{
                source = lettersSource
                path = /usr/local/sphinx/data/lettersIndexes
                docinfo = extern
                min_word_len = 3
                min_prefix_len = 6
                html_strip = 1
}
searchd
{
                listen = 192.168.0.14:3312
                listen = 192.168.0.14:9306:mysql41

                log = /usr/local/sphinx/data/searchd.log
                query_log = /usr/local/sphinx/data/query.log
                max_children = 20
                pid_file = /usr/local/sphinx/data/searchd.pid
}
```

Кодировка редактора Qt - utf8.
Содержимое логов запросов:

```
[Wed Feb 3 15:04:47.913 2016] 0.000 sec 0.000 sec [ext2/0/ext 0 (0,20)] [lettersIndex]
???????
[Fri Feb 5 10:25:22.623 2016] 0.000 sec 0.000 sec [ext2/0/ext 0 (0,20)] [lettersIndex]
?????»?»?µ????
[Wed Feb 3 15:05:22.284 2016] 0.000 sec 0.000 sec [ext2/0/ext 4 (0,20)] [lettersIndex]
ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð»ÐµÐ³Ð¸
```

Первый запрос - без кодека. Второй запрос - с кодеком 'windows-1251'. Третий запрос - из
терминала сервера (а так же из любой другой ОС Gnu/Linux).
Третий запрос принят в верной кодировке. Первый запрос содержит количество знаков равное
запрашиваемому слову. Второй запрос содержит в два раза больше знаков (что как бы
намекает на unicode...).

Результат выдал только третий запрос. Первые два выдавали пустой результат.

Как устранить эту проблему?

Содержимое раздела data передаваемого пакета
[image: Hex представление строки]

Comment: а в какой кодировке у Вас исходники?

Comment: "Кодировка редактора Qt - utf8". На всякий случай перепроверил - да, utf8.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте: `QString query = QString::fromUtf8("select id from lettersIndex where match('коллеги')");`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не вышло. Результат пустой. В логах запрошенное слово состоит из знаков вопросов в количестве длины слова (в данном случае для 'коллеги' это '???????' 7 символов).

Comment: А точно utf-8? Попробуйте: `QString query = QString::fromLocal8Bit("select id from lettersIndex where match('коллеги')");`

Comment: Я подвергся сомнению)) В общем в QtCreator во вкладке "Проекты" во вкладке "Редактор" опция "Кодировка файлов" установлена в UTF-8. Кроме того, проверил стандартными текстовыми редакторами (например, Notepad++) - кодировка UTF-8. Может быть есть более правильная и точная проверка?
И да, этот код выдал точно такой же результат.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда надо копать дальше. Берите какой-нибудь Wireshark и смотрите, что за строка отсылается на сервер

Comment: Спасибо. Понял, попробую.

Comment: Но пробуйте с  `QString::fromUtf8` это правильный вариант, а вот что там дальше делать, уже будет видно после анализа пакетов.

Comment: Хорошо. Заодно разберусь с Wireshark :)

Comment: @ixSci
Отследил своё сообщение. (Если что, я не силён в терминах этой области). Раздел "data" представляет мой запрос. Первые пять символов, видимо, служебные (33 00 00 00 03). После них идёт непосредственный текст запроса, в котором английские символы представлены верно, а русские знаками вопроса. Простым наблюдением выяснил, что каждый символ занимает 1 байт. Может нужна ещё какая-нибудь информация?

Comment: Прямо в вопрос(отредактировав его) положите hex представление строки, которое Вы получаете из дампа. Не весь пакет, а только строку

Comment: Прикрепил изображение. К сожалению, слабо видно выделение раздела data. Он начинается на четвёртой строке, седьмой байт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35339/discussion-between-ixsci-and-accumplus).