# Установка системной переменной MySQL в Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sphinx

Разрабатываю модуль поиска на Qt с использованием Sphinx.

Анализируемая база данных работает под СУБД Firebird и расположена на сервере под ОС Gnu/Linux. Кодировка базы UNICODE_FSS.

Клиент работает под ОС Windows.

Передача запроса демону Sphinx происходит через интерфейс MySQL (язык SphinxQL).

Подключение к базе:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "Sphinx");
db.setHostName("192.168.0.14");
db.setPort(9306);
if (!db.open())
    qDebug() << "Unable to open db!";
```

Отправка запроса:

```
QSqlQuery q(db);
QString query = QString::fromUtf8("select id from lettersIndex where match('коллеги')");
q.exec(query);
```

Через командную строку MySQL передача запроса происходит удачно. При этом для верной кодировки в my.ini необходимо инициализировать переменную:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

Однако, используя код Qt, представленный выше, кодировка передаваемого запроса конвертируется в ASCII, и русские буквы передаются знаками вопроса.

Я думаю, что проблема в этой глобальной переменной. Согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) MySQL, именно *эта* переменная не является динамической, и её нельзя изменять командой SET. Пробовал менять другие переменные, являющиеся динамическими (в частности character_set_client, так как она более всего похожа на нужную), но и это не принесло результатов. Кроме того, синтаксис, представленный в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html), не работает корректно.

```
SET GLOBAL character_set_client=utf8;
SET @@global.character_set_client=utf8;
```

Работает только вторая строка, но она не приносит никаких изменений.

В [документации](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-set.html) Sphinx существует своя конструкция SET, и скорее всего здесь работает она.

Вопрос такой: как в Qt установить системную переменную подобно тому, как она устанавливается в my.ini?

Дополнение:

Запускаю код в отладчике:

```
QSqlQuery q(db);
QString query = QString("select id from lettersIndex where match('коллеги')").toUtf8();
qDebug() << q.exec(query);
```

Значение переменной query в отладчике:
[image: Значение переменной query]

Однако, при двойном нажатии на значении переменной и последующем нажатии в иную область (или, например, нажатии Enter) русские буквы меняются на знаки вопроса. У меня есть подозрение, что в этой переменной изначально хранится текст в неверной кодировке.

[image: Значение переменной query после попытки изменения]

Comment: Скорее всего знаки вопроса вместо русских букв возвращает функция `QString::fromUtf8()`.

Comment: А выполнение запроса `set names utf8` в начале сессии не помогает ?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics , скорее всего нет. В отладчике эта переменная содержит верные данные. Но в Wireshark в передаваемом пакете уже содержатся знаки вопроса, будто бы кодировку портит сам драйвер MySQL.

Comment: @Mike ,QSqlQuery q(db);q Debug() << q.exec("SET NAMES utf8");
Сразу после db.open(). К сожалению, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Чтобы обойти проблему русских букв в UTF8 я в Qt использовал следующий трюк - названия файлов кодировал с помощью `QUrl::toPercentEncoding()`. Отладчик тоже ничего не показывал, а названия файлов получались из знаков вопроса.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics , Немного не уловил, куда мне это запихнуть?

Comment: если [этот ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489375/178576) уже неактуален, удалите его, пожалуйста.

Comment: А такой набор запросов не пробовали сразу после подключения к БД выполнять: `SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';` ?

Comment: Стоит попробовать `QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForCStrings(QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")); QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForLocale ( QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8"));`. Чел пишет, что это решило проблему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868631/qtsql-query-inserts-malformed-utf-8-text-to-mysql

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , там ещё продолжается обсуждение в чате. Я удалю, как только это будет возможно.

Comment: @alexis031182 , попробовал. Последний запрос не выполняется (QSqlQuery::exec() возвращает false). Первые два выполнились, но изменений не принесли.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics , к сожалению, в Qt5 нет метода QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(). Метод QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale() не принёс изменений.

Comment: К слову, я заметил одну особенность. Добавлю к вопросу её описание.

Comment: @AccumPlus, если ответ Вас удовлетворят — нажмите рядом с ним галочку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Краткий ответ:** в конфиге sphinx нужно выставить [mysql_version_string](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-mysql-version-string.html) во что-нибудь выше, чем 4.1.0. Лучше всего, конечно же, выставить это значение в ту версию MySQL, которую реально использует sphinx, во избежание возможных проблем в других частях.

---

**Полный ответ:**

Чтобы понять в чём проблема, нужно смотреть драйвер Qt для MySQL. В нём содержится следующая логика: при открытии соединения с MySQL Qt требует utf-8 от соединения:

```
mysql_set_character_set(d->mysql, "utf8");
```

Но не решается использовать `utf-8` по умолчанию, а спрашивает базу о том, какую же кодировку использовать:

```
QTextCodec* heuristicCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName(mysql_character_set_name(mysql));
```

С точки зрения логики, всё вроде верно: мы предлагаем использовать utf-8, а затем получаем кодировку, которую считает нужной использовать MySQL. 
Проблема заключается в том, что `mysql_character_set_name` не спрашивает базу о кодировке, но использует значение по умолчанию либо же то значение, которое было закешировано в вызове `mysql_set_character_set`. А в этом вызове есть такие строки:

```
if(strlen(cs_name) < MY_CS_NAME_SIZE &&
    (cs = get_charset_by_csname(cs_name, MY_CS_PRIMARY, MYF(0))))
{
    char buff[MY_CS_NAME_SIZE + 10];
    charsets_dir = save_csdir;
    /* Skip execution of "SET NAMES" for pre-4.1 servers */
    if(mysql_get_server_version(mysql) < 40100)
        return 0;
    sprintf(buff, "SET NAMES %s", cs_name);
    if(!mysql_real_query(mysql, buff, (uint)strlen(buff)))
    {
        mysql->charset = cs;
    }
}
```

`mysql->charset` это как раз то, что возвращает `mysql_character_set_name`. Так вот, как видно из кода выше, запрашиваемая кодировка не будет выставлена(закеширована) для версий сервера до 4.1. Но согласно документации, если [mysql_version_string](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-mysql-version-string.html) не установлена, тогда в качестве версии mysql используется версия sphinx, которая в настоящий момент 2.x.x, т.е. явно меньше 4.1.

Результатом всего этого безобразия выходит то, что mysql возвращает кодировку по умолчанию и Qt подчиняется. Кодировка по умолчанию, по всей видимости,— latin1. Вот Вы и имеет конвертацию в результирующем пакете. Поэтому решением является явное выставление версии MySQL в конфиге sphinx.